# Random float within a range?

Tags: c++, random, double

I am trying to create a random number between 15.00 and 40.00, for use in a calculation.  The specific task is to build a program that takes in the number of tickets sold and calculate the total income from these ticket sales, with three of the ticket types having a constant price value, and one of the ticket types having a random price value between $15.00 and $40.00.  How can I do this?

I've come close with this, but only if I declare the mystmax and mystmin as 'int'.  I would like them to be double, so I can have every decimal value between $15.00 and $40.00:

```
  unsigned seed = time(0);

    srand(seed);
    double mystery = (rand() % (mystmax - mystmin+1))+mystmin;
```

Here is the error I get when I try to have the min and max as doubles:

"Invalid operands of the types 'int' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'"

What can I do to remedy this?

Comment: [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution).

Comment: Do you really need a float? Or do you just need two decimal places? You say you need "every decimal value between $15.00 and $40.00" but that's either infinity (mathematically) or many millions (actual `double` range constraint)

Comment: Just 2 decimal places is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't.**

You neither need nor want floating point for currency.

There are ways to make it work ([`std::uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) will give you the floating-point random values), but plenty of problems with doing so (rounding errors for starters), and you just don't need all of the infinity decimals between those two money values.

So, stick with an integer, in your case counting *pennies* (cents?). Divide by 100 at the very end for output if you want to convert to whole units (dollars?).

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what you mean by this.  Where exactly should I be dividing by 100, and for what purpose?  When I do it at the very end for output as you say, I get a number that is far smaller than it should be.  If I do it in a few other places, it has no effect.  Can you elaborate on this a bit?

Comment: I assume you wish, at some point that you haven't shown us, to output a final dollar value to the screen, so that a human can see it. I'm suggesting that throughout your code you use an `int`, not a `double`, for your monetary value, and logically consider that value to be in pennies, not dollars. When you want to print the dollar value to the screen, divide by 100 (a dollar is 100 pennies, yes?). e.g. `std::cout << '$' << (myNumberOfPennies / 100.0) << '\n';` (plus some adjustments to ensure 2dp, but you have to do that already anyway)

Comment: Sorry, that took me a second to understand, but it worked perfectly.  Thanks!!

Comment: @jackwilliamson: Have fun!